# Video JS ie8 LOG: Error

Tags: internet-explorer-8, video.js

I'm having a bit of an issue with video js on ie8. I have a list a videos. When a user clicks on one of the links, I do a javascript call to get the proper video and video urls(all absolute urls). the video slated to work when the page loads works fine but if I try to switch to another video, the video player disappears and the script console shows a string "LOG:Error" over and over again...basically crashing ie8.

Here's the code I use to load a video:

```
 data = $.parseJSON(data);
        mp4_url  = data.mp4_url;
        webm_url = data.webm_url;
        flv_url  = data.flv_url;        
        var submission_id = data.submission_id;

        var video_player = '<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="'+player_width+'" height="'+player_height+'" poster="" data-setup="{}"> '
                                     + '<source id="mp4"   src="'+mp4_url+'" type="video/mp4" />'
                                     + '<source id="flash" src="'+flv_url+'" type="video/flv" />'
                                     + '<source id="webm"  src="'+webm_url+'" type="video/webm" />'
                                     + '</video>';
        $('#player').empty();
        $('#player').html(video_player);
        $('#player').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not following the API documents. I realized what I needed to do what put the video block into my template and then define a variable set to the player like so:

```
 var mplayer = _V_('video');
```

and then set the sources:

```
mplayer.src([{ type: "video/mp4", src: mp4_url },{ type: "video/webm", src: webm_url },{ type: "video/flv", src: flv_url }]);
```